# How to create a filter in SQL through a procedure or function?

Tags: sql, select, filter, procedure

I've tried to do it like this:

```sql
-- RF-001 Informe de ventas por cliente
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Ventas_cliente( DNI IN CHAR )
IS

BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM Pedidos_venta
  WHERE DNI_Cliente = DNI;
END Ventas_cliente;
```

When I run it, SQL Developer returns the next error:

> Error(5,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT
>   statement

Why is INTO needed to filter in this ocasion? How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on [Table-Valued Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Also, when you are developing the function, don't use `SELECT *`, you will need to specify the columns.